# How should I be referencing firebase data in Vue component?

Tags: firebase, vue.js

I can see the data in the Vue console but I'm getting an error in the console: 'Property or method "rsvp" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render.'

How should I be referencing the firebase data?

```
<template>
    <ul>
        <li
            v-for="(data, index) in rsvp"
            :key="index"
        >
            <div
                v-for="(name, index) in data.name"
                :key="index"
            >
                {{ name }}
            </div>
            <div v-if="data.dietRestrictions">
                Diet Restrictions: {{ data.dietRestrictions }}
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</template>

<script>

import { db } from "../../config/db";

export default {
    name: "Results",
    firebase: {
        rsvp: db.ref("rsvp"),
    },
}

</script>
```

Comment: Why Do you not write firebase object into `data()` ?

Answer (score 0):

I just forgot to declare rsvp in `data()`.

```
data() {
    return {
        rsvp: {},
    }
},
```